# Fake HDD partition table fix

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, mbr

I bought cheap 1TB external HDD on aliexpress. They are writing not to format exFAT partition, because it will break. 
Inside, there is only 160GB old HDD. I tried h2testw to prove, that the drive capacity is not good and to refund some money.

After destroying the data in **h2testw**, there is no option to use the drive anymore. There is missing MBR and partition table. Windows doesn't show the drive at all. 
When I'm trying to mount it directly to Ubuntu, there are a lot of errors in dmesg:

```
[  452.167661] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#7 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[  452.167666] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#7 CDB: Synchronize Cache(10) 35 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
[  452.167671] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sda, sector 0 flags 801
[  455.281515] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#20 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[  455.281519] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#20 CDB: Synchronize Cache(10) 35 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
[  455.281524] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sda, sector 0 flags 801
[  455.692577] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#21 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[  455.692580] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#21 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 80 00 00 08 00
[  455.692583] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sda, sector 128 flags 80700
[  455.692622] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#22 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[  455.692624] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#22 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 80 00 00 08 00
[  455.692626] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sda, sector 128 flags 0
[  455.692628] buffer_io_error: 59 callbacks suppressed
[  455.692629] Buffer I/O error on dev sda, logical block 16, async page read
```

**gparted** shows the drive after skipping a lot of errors, but can't format it, or create partition table

**fdisk** doesn't show the drive and can't open it

```
fdisk: cannot open /dev/sda: No such file or directory
```

**fsck** can't read superblock:

```
The superblock could not be read or does not describe a valid ext2/ext3/ext4 filesystem.
```

**mke2fs**

```
mke2fs: Device size reported to be zero.  Invalid partition specified, or
partition table wasn't reread after running fdisk
```

Can you please help me to restore the right capacity of the drive?

Comment: Don't waste your time: ask for a refund and bin the drive. You **should not** rely on these HDD's to store any data.

Comment: Are you using the external HDD enclosure it came in? Try a different one.

Comment: I mounted it directly to mi PC with SATA connection. I wanted to use it as normal external HDD without loosing data. 160GB would be enough for me.

Comment: If they are trying to pass off a dodgy 160GB disk as 1TB you need to return it. Who knows what's happened to that disk in the past?

Comment: You cannot restore a dead drive.